# Fancyapps overlay not showing

Tags: javascript, fancybox, overlay, fancybox-2

We are loading fancybox css file dynamically after page load and try to open fancybox with overlay active and custom html content.

Sometimes overlay doesn't appear. If we try to open fancybox with a delay, probability of getting no overlay is decreasing, but it is not totally gone away.

I have already created an issue for this problem: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/1126

That's how we initialize fancybox:

```
var fancyboxParams = {
  minHeight: 10,
  width: params.width || 'auto',
  height: params.height || 'auto',
  autoSize: false,
  autoWidth: params.width ? false : true,
  autoHeight: params.height ? false : true,
  autoHide: params.autoHide,
  topRatio: params.topRatio || topRatio,
  leftRatio: params.leftRatio || leftRatio,
  title: title,
  helpers: {
    title: (title && params.windowStyle !== 'seamless') ? {
      type: 'inside',
      position: 'top'
    } : null,
    overlay: (params.overlay != "false") ? {} : null
  },
  content: notificationBody,
  fixed: false, // HADDITION - scroll with the page 16.10.2015
  wrapCSS: (params.cssClass || "") + " " + "fancybox-" + (params.windowStyle || "seamless"),
  beforeShow: function () {
    cssCode && $('<style />').html(params.cssCode).prependTo(this.outer);
    try {
      javascriptCode && eval(javascriptCode);
      beforeShow.call(this); // change context
    }
    catch (err) {
      $.fancybox.close(true);
    }
  },
  afterClose: function () {
    $(".fancybox-segmentify").remove();
  }
};

if (params.isModal == 'true') {
  fancyboxParams.closeBtn = false;
  fancyboxParams.closeClick = false;
  fancyboxParams.keys = null;
  if (fancyboxParams.helpers.overlay) {
    fancyboxParams.helpers.overlay.closeClick = false;
  }
}

$.fancybox(fancyboxParams);
```

Comment: did you find any solution for it?